# Determining the running time of the following code (recursion with a loop inside)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time, time-complexity, catalan

I have the following code and need to determine the running time of this algorithm.

```
int res=0; 
if (n <= 1) 
    return 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    res += Catalan(i) * (Catalan(n - i - 1); 
return res;
```

I am having  a hard time to determine the running time because of the loop inside the recursion. I know I need to transform it to a regression formula and then analyze it but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: You could try and putting in some small values for `n` and then try to figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first idea, profile it with different sizes of input.

If you plot  a graph runtime over size of the input you will quite easily get an idea if it its O(N) or something like O(N²).

Then you have an idea what complexity you are looking for, take a close look at your code to find the format proof of your observation.

Comment: what you are suggesting is nice and all, but do you know how i transform it into a regression equation? what i mean is t(n)=t(n/2)+1 for example

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify your function to:

```
    for (int i=0; i< n; i++) 
        res += Catalan(i)*(Catalan(i-1); 
    return res;
```

this simplification should not affect the time complexity.

Let n = 1:

```
   1 
   /\
  0  0
```

then we will have 3 calls of Catalan function.

If n = 2, then for Catalan(i) we will have:

```
     2
     /
    1 
   /\ 
  0 0
```

and for Catalan(i-1)

```
   1 
   /\
  0  0
```

so in total we will have:

```
     2      
     /\    
    1  1   
   /\  /\  
  0 0 0  0
```

if i=3, then:

```
          3
       /     \
      2       2 
     /\       /\
    1  1     1  1
   /\  /\    /\ /\
  0 0 0  0  0 0 0 0
```

It seems to me like `O(2^n)` complexety